# SFTP using SOCKS proxy command with password authentication

Tags: shell, authentication, sftp, socks

We need to make SFTP connection to download file through SOCKS proxy.

Trying below way but it's not working.

```
sftp -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/nc -v -xexamplesocksproxy.com:1080 %h %p' user@remote
```

We do have user name and password for SOCKS proxy authentication but not sure where to put it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imo, `nc` does not support authentication.

You will need to use another implementation. For example the [`ncat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ncat.1.html) with its `--proxy-auth` switch.

According to [Is there a built-in way to proxy SSH through socks5?](https://serverfault.com/q/1050866/168875), this should do:

```
sftp -o ProxyCommand='ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy-auth username:password --proxy examplesocksproxy.com:1080 %h %p' user@remote
```